# Cordova Diagnostic Exception on Diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails()

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have to read data from an SD card in a device.

I first try to do it via [cordova-plugin-file](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file), but it just show me `file:///storage/emulated/0/` and not the sdcard directory.

I found out that I needed to use [cordova.plugins.diagnostic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic) to solve my problem, but when I use it (with `Diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails().then(OnSucceedFunction, OnFailureFunction)`*), it "work" on on web view (by send me the error `cordova_not_available`, but it's logic), but in android app, nothing append on the app, and I need to use android console to see:

```
E/Diagnostic: Exception occurred onRequestPermissionsResult: No context found for request id=1000
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext.error(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

and i found nothing on stack overflow or anywhere on internet, so, I'm here to ask for some help

*OnSucceedFunction and OnFailureFunction are just to make you understand what am I doing, I know if I write it it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need ionic [Diagnostic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file
```

> According to @MarcusIII (His answer)  [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/needs-to-enable-storage-permission-manually-in-android-device-while-downloading-file-ionic-2-cordova-file-plugin/89262/3)

```
this.diagnostic.requestExternalStorageAuthorization().then(()=>{
//your permission 
}).catch(error=>{
//Error Handling part
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need to read from SDCard, as per the documentation, your code needs to be modified like this

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'file_name', readFile, onErrorReadFile);

function readFile(fileEntry) {

  fileEntry.file(function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {
      console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
      displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);

  }, onErrorReadFile);
}

function onErrorReadFile(error) {
  console.log('error reading', error);
}
```

[cordova.file.externalRootDirectory](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#android-file-system-layout) will help you point to your SDCard.

Comment: It's not working, that why i have to use cordova plugin diagnostic

Comment: What issue do you face when you try access the SDcard this way?

Comment: as said, instead of getting the actual path of the SDcard, I get file:///storage/emulated/0/, which is not the correct path